# Difficulty using var value in an elseif statement after value is changed in a query

Tags: php, variables, key-value, if-statement

**UPDATE -** I finally figured this out, and I've added the answer below :-) *(I'll accept it as answered as soon as the system allows me to)*

---

I think that I'm probably doing something very simple incorrectly (i.e. calling the variable incorrectly), as I've had similar issues in several situations.

I am creating a password reset form and would like to include the various steps and form sections on one page. I'm doing this using a series of elseif statements to determine which html code to display and/or php script to execute, and changing the value of the variable as a series of queries succeed or fail.

I've tested the queries and the var value changes correctly (I've echo'd the value at each step to confirm that) but the correct result isn't being displayed unless the var value is set manually.

For purposes of the question I've included 2 simplified snippets - a very basic scenario (which I can easily apply to my code), and a simplified version of my code, and I'd be happy to share the full code if that's preferable.

**EDIT -** I've also tried calling `GLOBAL $status;` before setting a new value for $status, on the off-chance that was the problem.

Basic Scenario:

```
<?php
//session_start and connect to database 
$status="start";
?>
<?php $status="start"; ?>
<?php if ($status == "start") { ?>
    Check if expiry valid & retrieve info 
    <?php $status = "expiry_ok"; ?>    
<?php }
elseif ($status == "expiry_ok") 
{ ?>
    Date is Valid
<?php } ?>
```

Simplified Version of Query:

```
<?php if ($status == "start"){  
    //Identify the $temp_password by removing the URL
    $restorepasslink="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $new_pass = str_replace("http://click2fit.com/demo/restorepass.php/", "", $restorepasslink);
    //Query db to check if expiry_date has passed
    $qry="SELECT * FROM password_reset WHERE temp_password = '$new_pass'";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);
    if($result) {
            $token = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);            
            $token_expiry_date = $token['expiry_date']; 
            // Other $token values are also set here 
            if($date < $token_expiry_date) {
                $status = "expiry_ok";
            }else {
                $status = "expiry_notok";
           }  
   }
?>
```

*Note: Since most of the tutorial are still written for mysql queries instead of PDO, I'm first trying to get it all to work that way before switching it over to PDO.*

Comment: `mysql_*` are deprecated - see https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-5.5.0alpha2/NEWS

Comment: @JonathanKuhn: I know :-) I just thought it would be easiest if I stripped the code down to only that which was relevant to the question :-)

Comment: But it does not help at all.

Comment: SO is full of people yelling "PDO! SQL INJECTION!" blah blah blah. Any question with mysql_* functions, test code or not, will get the same 5 responses (comments/answers) saying "PDO! SQL INJECTION". Also, on the subject, the global keyword won't change anything to variables defined in the global scope (outside of a function/method/class).

Comment: @JonathanKuhn: You're so right :-D I just edited the question because of that ;-) Would you mind clarifying what you were saying about global variables? This is the 1rst time I've actually had reason to try using them, so I'm not quite up to speed on them

Comment: @Tigger: I'm using PDO's for the actual code, I just find it easier to get it working with mysql queries first (in part because most of the tutorial are still written for mysql queries instead of PDO)

Comment: To make sure I'm understanding this correctly: your problem is that if you don't include `global`, then later in the code the value `$status` doesn't "stick"?  If that's the case, make sure you're not dealing with a scope issue.  (Define status, call function that plays with status, return from function -> status resets.)

Comment: @GigaWatt: I'm honestly not that familiar with global variables, I just tried it here before posting the question on the off-chance that's what was causing the problem. I don't think that's the issue, but if you think it might be would you mind clarifying your  suggestion?

Comment: The `global` keyword is for use within functions, not outside of them. Try the samples on: http://php.net/global

Comment: @Tigger: I'd only tried using global variables as a last-resort effort before posting the question (and that was actually the page that I'd tried basing it on ;-) ). But thankfully all this brainstorming gave me another idea to try and I finally figured out that the problem was with the way I was setting up the if statements and I've added the answer below :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing the initial if statement:

```
if ($status == "start"){...}
```

and simply starting the elseif statements with

```
if ($status == "expiry_ok"){...}   
elseif (...)
```

I also removed the initial declaration of the $status="start";